# Null Pointer exception occurs when back pressed on a particular fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Null Pointer Exception occurs at times randomly. Occurs mostly when pressed the backpressed from a particular fragment.

Exception occurs when tries to pass a param called "userregid" using Volley.

```
 params.put("userregid", Utils.getString(((BaseActivity)getActivity()).get_hospital_userreg_id()));
```

I wrote a method in a BaseActivity to identify the hospital_userreg_id according to the conditions. This is the function ,

```
 public int  get_hospital_userreg_id() {

    int userreg_id = 0;

    switch (AppConst.HOSPITAL_CURRENT_ID) {

        case 36:
            userreg_id = AppConst.HOSP_ONE_USERREG_ID;
            break;
        case 37:
            userreg_id = AppConst.HOSP_TWO_USERREG_ID;
            break;
    }

    return userreg_id;
}
```

I feel that the issue is related to calling the function from the fragment. Any solutions ?

Comment: This code needs Debugging nothing else. Try to find out which object is null on `onbackPressed()`.

Comment: hey you are passing integer to string that is wrong otherwise typecast it...

Comment: @Dilip I'm using Utils.getString to typeCast it to String. It's working perfectly in most conditions. but at some point it show's null pointer exception.

'public static String getString(int number) {
        return String.valueOf(number);
    }'

Comment: hard to say without stacktrace, but `getActivity()` probably returns `null` because your fragment is already gone away from the activity

Comment: hey @Clint Paul  please check null before put in params like  if(null!= Utils.getString(((BaseActivity)getActivity()).get_hospital_userreg_id())){params.put("userregid", Utils.getString(((BaseActivity)getActivity()).get_hospital_userreg_id()));        
 }

Comment: @JohnnyAW 
So,  should I call like ((BaseActivity)getContext) instead of ((BaseActivity)getActivity) ?

Comment: @Dilip 
Is it a practical solution ? coz then I have to put null pointer check in every network call

Comment: I don't know, depends on what you need. I think `getContext` would also return `null` in this case

Comment: @JohnnyAW , Yes tried with getContext too. getting nullpointer at some stage. So , is it better if I write the method from some other class instead from a BaseActivity ?

Comment: you could try to use another hook, like `onDetach` so you know, that after this your fragment is not longer available on the activity

Comment: @JohnnyAW okay I'll try both ways and will update once the issue is solved. Thanks for your time